# How to put Image Behind navigation drawer items android studio? example shown below

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigationbar

I want to create a navigation layout like this:-

[image]

this is my drawer view code :-

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/group1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_library"

        android:title="@string/library" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_playlists"

        android:title="@string/playlists" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_queue"

        android:title="@string/playing_queue" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_nowplaying"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:title="@string/now_playing" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_filemanager"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:title="@string/file_manager" />

</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/group2"
    android:checkableBehavior="none">
    <item

        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings" />

    <item

        android:id="@+id/nav_help"
        android:title="@string/help_and_feedback" />

    <item

        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:title="@string/about"
        />

</group>
```

and i have a drawer layout with a Navigation View implemented.
Can someone suggest me a method to make that kind of navigation bar in android?

thanks in advance...

Comment: First of all I would suggest you to change your navigation drawer implementation with one using custom xml instead of menu.xml. Try searching for navigation drawer using recycler view. That you can customise quite easily as compared to this implementation

Answer (score 0):

implement custom NavigationDrawer with Recyclerview.In the Adapter of recyclerview you can load the item as you like. Follow [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html)